# how to Load subdomain like subdirectory in apache?

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I am working on an android application witch connect to an web api written in php.
I setup a subdomain by this configuration in my httpd-vhost conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/Clinic"
ServerAlias Clinic.localhost
ServerName Clinic.localhost
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/Clinic">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

this setting work when I connect to that like this :

> http://clinic.localhost:8080

but now I want to connect to this API from android device. there is no dns server and I must connect to this API by server IP now when I am trying to connect by this url:

> http://192.168.1.102:8080/clinic

I get 404 error and my system cannot resolve host.

Comment: it's caused by your port, use the 80. and make alias /clinic

Comment: excuse me. i set port in real word but i forget to type in my question. i correct my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. in my httpd-vhost config file i have not a virtual host for my root and because of this apache could not recognize host root folder. I add this config to my config file and every things is ok.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```